# Is el having a ref or jquery reference ? code snippet below

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

```
this.$el = el instanceof Backbone.$ ? el : Backbone.$(el);

this.el = this.$el[0];
```

What does Backbone.$ mean in the code snippet below ? is it the Jquery reference to backbone ?

Comment: Check the answer to the duplicate, that covers `Backbone.$` quite well. Basically, `Backbone.$` is jQuery's `$` without any possible namespace or naming issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update: `el instanceof Backbone.$` mean check if `el` is jQuery/zepto object or not. `Backbone.$` is backbone variable and used as alias for jQuery/zepto.

from the doc http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar

> If jQuery is included on the page, each view has a `$` function that
>   runs queries scoped within the view's element. If you use this scoped
>   jQuery function, you don't have to use model ids as part of your query
>   to pull out specific elements in a list, and can rely much more on
>   HTML class attributes. It's equivalent to running:
>   `view.$el.find(selector)`

Comment: So this means that. 

If the jquery selector of an html element (this.$el) is there in the view with backbone as a reference (Backbone.$) then the jquery reference of that element is it's reference (el and not this.$el ) else it's a jquery reference of the Backbone view ?

Comment: it still isn't very clear to me.

Comment: Can you take me further with this ?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. That helped.